# It keeps creating another restaurant

Tags: sql, mariadb

My intention is to get the rating from the reviews table and update the column called average_rating in the restaurants table. I want to specifically update the first restaurant but it keeps creating a new restaurant in my table

```
 var sql = "INSERT into restaurant_reviews.restaurants(average_rating) SELECT AVG(rating) FROM restaurant_reviews.reviews INNER JOIN restaurant_reviews.restaurants ON restaurants_idrestaurant = idrestaurant
```

The restaurant that I want to update:

[image]

It keeps creating a new one:

[image]

Comment: Use `UPDATE` to update existing rows. `INSERT` inserts new rows.

Comment: Where do I put the SET?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE r
SET r.average_rating = AVG(v.rating)
FROM restaurant_reviews.restaurants r
INNER JOIN restaurant_reviews.reviews v ON r.idrestaurant = v.restaurants_idrestaurant;
```

That said, you shouldn't store calculated values in the database as this violates the rules of RDBMS normalization.  Nonetheless, the above code provides the UPDATE syntax you're after.

The revised, tested, and functional MariaDB syntax is...

```
UPDATE restaurant_reviews.restaurants r
SET r.average_rating = (SELECT AVG(v.rating) FROM restaurant_reviews.reviews v WHERE v.restaurants_idrestaurant = r.idrestaurant);
```

Comment: FROM is not valid at this position.

Comment: This is valid SQL, but may not be compatible with your particular engine.  Which specific database are you using?

Comment: I am using MariaDB

Comment: Updated with MariaDB-specific syntax.  If that meets your need, please mark this as the answer so that others with similar questions may find help too.

Comment: Error code :1111 invalid use of group function

Comment: Updated once more.  MariaDB apparently needs some very specialized SQL to function.  Please be sure to mark as answered.